# Stop LoginActivity from popping out onResume()

Tags: android, authentication, onresume, onpause, main-activity

I got two activities.....`LoginActivity`(Launcher Activity) and `MainActivity`. When the app is installed and started the `LoginActivity` is invoked and on entering the username and password, it authenticate from a server and starts the `MainActivity`. This works fine.

when the app is minimized or Paused using backbutton or homebutton and resumed again i want the app to resume from the MainActivity. How can that be done...I am a beginner...please help!!Thanks.

Comment: invoke MainActivity in onPause().

Comment: did u mean at onPause() of MainActivity??

Comment: let me try......i will come back to u...Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set Global `boolean` variable and set it to true when you successfully login and check it on resume activity of `LoginActivity` and start an Intent of `MainActivity`. Here is the code..

```
boolean mainActi = false;
mainActi = true;

@Override
protected void onResume() {

super.onResume();

f(mainActi) {
     Intent i1  = new Intent(MainActivity.this,LogIn.class);
     startActivity(i1);
     mainActi = false;
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

By finishing() your LoginActivity(Launcher Activity) , and storing your data ( LoginActivity ) in Bundle argument in Bundle .... and restoring that data in onResume() of MainActivity with the help of Bundle of argument .

Edited :

Create a global_Bundle_Argument LoginActivity .

Bundle bun ;

and , inside onCreate put 
this.bun = bun ;
bun.putString(key, value) ;

send this bundle argument with intent :
intent.putExtra(name, value) ;

and get this bundle argument in MainActivity() ;
Bundle bun = intent.getBundleExtra(name) .